# 'using statics' and methods with same name

Tags: c#, static, using

I have 2 static classes "Marshaler" that are handling the de/serialization of data types, the first one is part of my library, it serializes the default types such as uint, the second one is part of my application and serializes specific types.

Quick Example:

```
// LibMarshaler.cs:
public static class LibMarshaler
{
    public static void Write(Archive a, string b)
    {
        Write(b.Length); // Works
        Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b)); // Works
    }

    public static void Write(Archive a, int b)
    {
        a.Write(b);
    }

    public static void Write(Archive a, byte[] b)
    {
        a.AppendBytes(b);
    }
}

// AppMarshaler.cs
using static LibMarshaler;

public static class AppMarshaler
{
    public static void Write(Archive a, CustomType1 b)
    {
        Write(a, b.exampleString); // error, can't find the function
        Write(a, b.customType2); // works, is part of the same file
    }

    public static void Write(Archive a, CustomType2 b)
    {
        Write(a, b.exampleString); // error, can't find the function
    }
}
```

I realized it's because AppMarshaler is defining it's own "Write" functions, therefore the C# compiler cancel every other one defined in other files. But I don't have any other choice, because all my code is generated and lies on those functions.

Is there any way to go around it, and why is it even like that ? I am not overriding any existing function signature ..

Comment: `LibMarshaler.write`

Comment: Generated code should use something like `global::The.Full.Namespace.LibMarshaler.Write` - it doesn't need to be pretty, but it does need to guard against name collisions. The oposite of `using static`, essentially.

Comment: The reason I'm not using the fully qualified name is because it's generated, and I can't know which Marshaler it belongs tho. Later, there is chances to be more than 1 application marshaler, so it needs to be scalable.